# Updating cordova-plugin-sqlite -- how to load my existing database?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I released an Ionic app earlier this year for both iOS and Android which makes use of [cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage). In preparing for a new release, today I updated the Android and iOS cordova platforms and updated all plugins.

In my existing version of the app, my call to `$cordovaSQLite.openDB` does not specify a location. This is fine for the version of the plugin I am using in production. However, the newer versions require a location to be specified when opening the DB.

I have no idea what I am supposed to put for the location when trying to open an existing DB from a version of sqlite where no location was specified. Using the option `'default'` isn't working, it is just creating a new database on both Android and iOS. This is not acceptable as this new DB has none of the user's stored data.

How can I specify a location that will always correspond to the location from older versions of the sqlite plugin?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @PhilMitchell I'll post the code that ended up working for me. I think something was wrong with my android config because "default" did end up working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that ended up working for me:

```
if (window.cordova) {
    if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "database.db", iosDatabaseLocation: 'Documents'});
    }
    else {
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "database.db", location: 'default'});
    }           
}
else {
    db = window.openDatabase("database.db", '1.0', 'auto', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting that. Looks like Documents dir is working for you on iOS. Wish I could say the same :)

Comment: @PhilMitchell No problem, the documentation also suggests trying "default" and "Library" if you have not done so yet.